# How to use Acro with English and another RTL language

Tags: nomenclature, xepersian, acro

I would like to use Persian or Hebrew and English in  Acro package, but it doesn't work simply, and for the list of acronyms, I want it to fit within the same line.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, openany, notoc]{report}
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[Kashida]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=.8]{Arial}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=.8]{Arial}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{Arial}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
    only-used = false,
    first-style=default,% 
    hyperref =true,
    %list-heading = section,
    group-citation = true,
    label = true,
    only-used = false,  
    %short-format = {\scshape},     
    extra-style = default,
    %page-style = comma ,%show linked pages but with a problem in arabic
    sort = true ,
    list-style =  longtable-rev
}
\DeclareAcronym{rs}{
  short = RS,
  long = Remote Sensing ,
  foreign =  \rl{الاستشعار عن بعد} ,
  %foreign-lang = Persian,
  %extra = \begin{RTL} \rl{الاستشعار عن بعد} \end{RTL},
  class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{gis}{
    short = GIS,
    long = Geographical Information Systems,
    foreign = \rl{نظم المعلومات الجغرافية} ,
    %foreign-lang = english,
    %extra = \begin{RTL} \rl{نظم المعلومات الجغرافية} \end{RTL} ,
    %foreign = \rl{نظم المعلومات الجغرافية} ,
    class = abbrev
}
\begin{document}
\begin{LTR}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{description}%
{\list{}{\leftmargin=0pt
\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
\let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}%
{\endlist}
\makeatother
\begin{description}
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,  name={Acronyms}]
\end{description}
\end{LTR}
\lr{text example}\\ 
\lr{\ac{rs}}\\
\lr{\ac{gis}}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not so easy with `acro` v2.x. Should be doable with `acro` v3.x by defining suitable templates for the first appearance and for the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using an older version of `acro`.  With the version 3 syntax and `babel` in LuaLaTeX, you can define new `acro` templates with the formatting you want.

You would need to tweak this further if you need to, for example, insert `extra` information into the list of acronyms.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, openany, notoc]{report}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular, english]{babel}
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[version=3]{acro}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import=fa, onchar=ids fonts]{persian} % You can also call this farsi, or something else.

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer = HarfBuzz }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures={Common,Rare}, Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures={Common,Rare}]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}
\babelfont[persian]{rm}
          {Amiri}
% Set \babelfont[persian]{sf} here, if needed.
\babelfont[persian]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\NewAcroTemplate{custom-inline}{%
  \begin{otherlanguage}{english}%
  \acrowrite{long}%
  \acspace%
  (\acrowrite{short}%
  \acroifT{alt}{ \acrotranslate{or} \acrowrite{alt}}%
  )%
  \acroifT{foreign}{\acspace\acrowrite{foreign}}%
  \end{otherlanguage}%
}

\NewAcroTemplate[list]{custom-description}{%
  \acroheading%
  \acropreamble%
  \begin{description}
    \acronymsmapF{%
      \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
      \item[\acrowrite{short}\acroifT{alt}{/\acrowrite{alt}}]
        \acrowrite{list}%
        \acroifT{foreign}{\hfill\acrowrite{foreign}}%
      \end{otherlanguage}
    }%
    {\item\AcroRerun}
  \end{description}
}

\acsetup{
    list/template=custom-description,
    list/sort=true,
    list/display=used,
    list/include=abbrev,
    foreign/display=true,
    make-links=true,
    first-style=custom-inline,
    subsequent-style=custom-inline
}
\DeclareAcronym{rs}{
    short = RS,
    long = Remote Sensing ,
    foreign =  {الاستشعار عن بعد} ,
    foreign-babel = persian,
    tag = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{gis}{
    short = GIS,
    long = Geographical Information Systems,
    foreign = {نظم المعلومات الجغرافية} ,
    foreign-babel = persian,
    tag = abbrev
}


\begin{document}
\printacronyms[name={Abbreviations}, include=abbrev]

{text example}\\
{\ac{rs}}\\
{\ac{gis}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus/Amiri sample]

You can use any of your system or OpenType fonts in place of Libertinus and Amiri; these are just examples.  To use Persian as the main language, add `main` to the option list of `\babelprovide[import=fa, main, onchar=ids fonts]{persian}`.  To support Hebrew, add `\babelprovide[import=he, onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}`, and possibly define `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}`, etc.

To keep compiling in XeLaTeX, remove the `onchar=ids fonts` option, the `Renderer=HarfBuzz` option, and change `bidi=basic` to `bidi=default`.  You will lose the ability to type in Arabic or Hebrew script and have Babel automatically detect the language, changing direction and fonts.

Comment: This is a great workaround, but in my case, I can't use it since my whole document is written with xepersian package since this package is well developed to solve many issues for documents with RTL and LTR languages especially references and citations.

Comment: I'm not sure if `subsequent-style=custom-inline` makes much sense: the `custom-inline` template does not distinguish between first and subsequent calls (which could be done with `\acroiffirst(TF)`) which means that with this setup each call of an acronym behaves like it was the first call.

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour I’m not very familiar with `xepersian`. The solution should be adaptable to it. Here, I solve the language problem by always switching to English when formatting an acronym, since you said you wanted this particular format. You could also use `iflang` to switch formats based on the current language.

Comment: @cgnieder There are definitely many ways this template could be improved. Right now, it just gives the format specified in the question, and nothing else. If this is an issue, you could keep `first-style=custom-inline`, but switch to *e.g.* `subsequent-style=short`.

Comment: Well, not an issue for me :) I just wanted to mention the potential problem.

Comment: @cgnieder I think my advice here would be for authors not to lock themselves into using a different style for the first appearance of an acronym, by coding it into the format itself. There’s a built-in command for that!

Comment: @Davislor I know my way around `acro` ;) It is built in different templates (`long-short`, `footnote`,…) by using the switch `\acroiffirstTF`. Actually I need to check if that's still necessary now that there is `subsequent-style`. 

Comment: @cgnieder You certainly do! It’s great work. And I didn’t mean to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Davislor I know you didn't :)